# reusing sockets with WinSocket client/server application

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets

I have 2 simple applications, one client and one server. The client connects to the server and the server sends data to the client. In the main loop of the client application, I'm closing the socket and creating a new one every time I want to receive another piece of information. It works but it doesn't look right to me. Is this right? Do I really need to close and reopen a socket every time, or is there another way to do this?

client:

```
    int main(){
    DWORD id;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    WSADATA wsas;
    WORD wersja;
    int recv_size;
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE WINAPI funkcja = getCommend;

    watek = CreateThread(NULL, 0, funkcja, 0, 0, &id);



    wersja = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
    WSAStartup(wersja, &wsas);


    memset((void *)(&sa), 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("25.62.229.110");

    int result;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    result = connect(s, (struct sockaddr FAR *) &sa, sizeof(sa));
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nBłąd połączenia!");
        return 1;
    }

    int a;
    if ((recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, SIZE, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recv failed\n");
    }
    else{
        while (result != SOCKET_ERROR){
            //printf("%s\n", server_reply);     
            closesocket(s);
            Sleep(1000);
            s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            result = connect(s, (struct sockaddr FAR *) &sa, sizeof(sa));
            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR){
                break;
            }
            result = recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, SIZE, 0);
        }
    }
    getchar();
    closesocket(s);
    TerminateThread(watek, NULL);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

server:

```
int main(){
DWORD id;
SOCKET s, new_socket;
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE WINAPI funkcja = getCommend;
struct sockaddr_in sa, sc;
WSADATA wsas;
int c;
watek = CreateThread(NULL,0,funkcja,0,0,&id);

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsas);

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//memset((void *)(&sa), 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(PORT);
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr FAR*)&sa, sizeof(sa));
listen(s, 5);
puts("Czekam na polaczenie...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while ((new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sc, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    //puts("polaczenie zaakceptowane");
    send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
}
if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Nie udane połaczenie, blad nr : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
TerminateThread(watek, NULL);   
getchar();
}
```

Comment: Eh  ... you don't close the socket and keep using it?

Comment: "closesocket(s);" hm?

Comment: I'm saying the better way is: Don't close the socket and keep using it. What makes you think that you need to close the socket? It's connection to the server is maintained, even after receiving a set of data. There is no reason to close it after each successfull recv() call.

Comment: Both of your codes are wrong, but primarily your server. Your server accepts a new connection before sending a new message, and does not close the previous connection.  Your client thus has to reconnect each time.  You need to change both sides to reuse the existing connection they already have. And you need to frame your messages so the client knows where one message ends and the next message begins. You cannot assume a 1-to-1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()` in TCP, only in UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well , some of things here are not very common.

first, you usually name your variables in English, not other languages that are written in latin alphabet. I may get downvote for that, but that is the common practice for a reason.

second of all, I'd prefere use the C++ standard over OS specific API. 
why not go with `std::thread` instead of WinApi thread? it's much more simple, short and elegant.

third, you code is 100% procedural. you don't have a standard C++ socket class, but it doesn't mean you can't (or shouldn't) write your own Socket class which handles in elegant way the creation, binding, sending and receiving functionality.

fourth, `s` is not a good name for a variable even if MSDN examples so. `acceptingSocket` might be.

about your actual question:
you have many options here, the 3 I can think of:
1) not close the socket and keep on receiving data inside a while loop.
 
pros: easy to write. when the server has new data the client gets it right away.
cons: this is not a good way when your server has more the few connections at each time because then it will crash.

2) let the server pack the data. then the client open a connection in pre-defined intervals, ask for all the accumulated data at once and receive it.
pros: the most CPU resource saving out of the three
options.
cons : your client will not get the data right away, but in a pre-defined intervals

3) let the client send the local IP and port to the server in the begining of each session. then let the client keep a bounded socket on the local host waiting for connections. every time the server has something new to tell the client - it just use the saved IP and port to connect to the client, send the data and close the connection. the client then returns to wait for new connections. this way
pros: in this case the server will have as few as possible connections in each time, wich is a good thing if you intent your server to server many clients.
cons: the weight actually falls on the client, which in many cases no the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The usual one-connection approach is:

```
Create socket
bind socket
Listen on socket
newsocket = accept on socket
while no accept errors
    while newsocket connected and error free
        process newsocket
    newsocket = accept on socket
```

Multiple connections can be handles several ways.

Multithreaded:

```
create thread pool
Create socket
bind socket
Listen on socket
while no errors
    newsocket = accept on socket
    hand newsocket off to thread pool for processing
```

Monothread [select](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=select) based

```
Create socket
bind socket
Listen on socket
add socket to readFD  list
while no errors
    select on readFD list
    if socket selected
        newsocket = accept on socket
        add newsocket to readFD  list
    while other sockets selected
        process other sockets
```